# Handling missing file download links without request on the same page

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

What's the best practice to handle clicks on file download links when the respective files are missing?

The specific situation is that attachment entities exist in the DB, pointing to file names only and the file storage path can be configured individually/separately. This is for a legacy app and has to be supported.

Is this possible? How does such code look like? I tried

```
    if ( file.canRead() )
    {
        byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray( file );

        // goes to code like here: http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/05/pdf-handling.html
        downloadFile( attachment.getFileName(), data );
    }
    else
    {
        this.log.errorv( "Attachment {0} not found in configured storage path {1}", file, this.storagePath );

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        facesContext.addMessage( null,
                                 new FacesMessage( FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Failed.",
                                                   "Downlosding file " + file + " failed! File doesn't exist in the configured storage path " + this.storagePath ) );

        // ???
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }
```

but this results in

```
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Kein Element gefunden
Adresse: https://localhost:8181/cmc-compliance/view/prototype/collisionManager.xhtml
Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 1:
```

(`<rant>`OMG, I **<strike>HATE</strike>**... eh **DISLIKE** int18ned error messages... someone should get rid of the person who thought this is a good idea... `</rant>`)

OK, the above means something like "XML processing error: no element found + Line 1, Column 1"

My code is obviously not the right way to do it...

I'm using the JSF code in a datatable:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{attachmentManager.downloadAttachment(att)}">
    <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="page_white.png" />
    <h:outputText value="#{att.fileName}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

What I'd ideally want is to display a JSF message (or PrimeFaces growl) and then leave the page as is, that is without issuing a full request on the same page again.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `facesContext.responseComplete();` you're basically preventing JSF from rendering the response. Hence the client retrieves a completely empty response. The webbrowser is trying to make its best out of it. All the webbrowser knows is that the requested resource has a `.xhtml` file extension. So the webbrowser presumes that it's some XML content. Then the webbrowser tries to parse the empty response as XML. But it failed miserably with the given error as there are no XML elements at all. A XML well formed document is namely required to have *at least* one root XML element.

Remove the `facesContext.responseComplete();` line and just return from the method the usual way. You should *only* use `facesContext.responseComplete();` when you've *already* written to the response yourself, such as providing a file download in this particular case.

---

> *OMG, I HATE int18ned error messages... someone should get rid of the person who thought this is a good idea...*

Just change the operating system platform default locale accordingly in platform specific settings. In case of Windows, a related answer with a screenshot can be found here: [Getting OS language in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862507/getting-os-langage-in-java/10862745#10862745). If the program itself (e.g. Firefox/Chrome) has also some locale-related settings as well, you might want to change it in the program itself as well.

Comment: As usual, thanks BalusC for the answer. This however will reload the whole page. Is there a way to just leave the page as is and have the FacesMessage displayed, e.g. by using `<p:commandLink ajax="true" ...>`?

Comment: That's not possible. You can't download files by ajax. Your best bet would be to set the URL to the file as a bean property and then conditonally render it into some JS which opens it by `window.location`. E.g. `<h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty bean.downloadURL}">window.location='#{bean.downloadURL}';</h:outputScript>`. Let the ajax link/button update its parent as well as the message.

Comment: Heh... complicated. Sort of. I'll check if the file really exists and won't display a link then. Thanks for helping!